# Dataproc : Submit a Spark Job through REST API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

We are using GoogleCloudPlatform for big-data analytics. For processing we are currently using the google cloud dataproc & spark-streaming.

I want to submit a Spark job using the REST API, but when I am calling the URI with the api-key, I am getting the below error!

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

URI :- https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/orion-0010/regions/us-central1-f/clusters/spark-recon-1?key=AIzaSyA8C2lF9kT*************SGxAipL0

I created the API from the google console> API manager

Answer (score 2):

While API keys can be used for associating calls with a developer project, it's not actually used for authorization. Dataproc's REST API, like most other billable REST APIs within Google Cloud Platform, uses [oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) for authentication and authorization. If you want to call the API programmatically, you'll likely want to use one of the client libraries such as the [Java SDK for Dataproc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/dataproc/v1) which provides convenience wrappers around the low-level JSON protocols, as well as giving you [handy thick libraries for using oauth2 credentials](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2).

You can also experiment with the direct REST API using Google's [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/dataproc/dataproc/v1/) where you'll need to click the button on the top right that says "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0".

I also noticed you used us-central1-f under the `regions/` path for the Dataproc URI; note that Dataproc's regions don't map one-to-one with Compute Engine zones or regions; rather, Dataproc's regions will each contain multiple Compute Engine zones or regions. Currently there is only one Dataproc region available publicly, which is called `global` and is capable of deploying clusters into all Compute Engine zones. For an easy illustration of using an oauth2 access token, you can simply use `curl` along with `gcloud` if you have the `gcloud` CLI installed:

```
PROJECT='<YOUR PROJECT HERE>'
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(gcloud beta auth application-default print-access-token)
curl \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT}/regions/global/clusters
```

Keep in mind that the `ACCESS_TOKEN` printed by gcloud here by nature expires (in about 5 minutes, if I remember correctly); the key concept is that the token you pass along in HTTP headers for each request will generally be a "short-lived" token, and by design you'll have code which separately fetches new tokens whenever the access tokens expire using a "refresh token"; this helps protect against accidentally compromising long-lived credentials. This "refresh" flow is part of what the thick auth libraries handle under the hood.